# Creating context and frameBuffer in Android NDK opengles 2.0?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I've created opengles2.0 project for ios which displays the mesh from the given vertex Buffer object(VBO) and indices array,

In which these are the basics things i followed,
1) Creating EaglLayer,EaglContext.
2) Generated FrameBuffer, RenderBuffer ,DepthBuffer.
3) Compiled the shaders.
4) initialized uniforms and attributes and other needed stuffs.
It's working fine.

Now i'm working on opengles2.0  for Android NDK which expected to do the same. But i struck with following, 
1) Creating the context.
2) Generating FrameBuffer, RenderBuffer ,DepthBuffer.

I googled for tutorials, i did't find right stuff.

EAGL is not available for Android NDK, is there any other interface for support ?
Please guide me with tutorials or sample codes ?

Edit 
I'm trying for the app that uses the NDK for OpenGL rendering code, but still has Java code for the activity.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you trying to write a purely native app? Or an app that uses the NDK for OpenGL rendering code, but still has Java code for the activity, etc?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Trying for the app that uses the NDK for OpenGL rendering code, but still has Java code for the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and now the project is working well with android NDK too.
I referred the "Hello gl2" example that comes with Android NDK which i downloaded from [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

In "Hello gl2" example they used EGL interface for creating context and frame buffers,DepthBuffers etc. needed. After initialising the context and Buffers they proceeded with normal opengles2.0 codes. I implemented the same steps in my project , it is working fine.

Thank You.